# discord.js getting each list for users for reactions

Tags: javascript, foreach, bots, discord.js

ok so I have been wroking on this for a while not I am making a vote bot and have gotten stuck on this part of the code I am its meant to show a list of each user that has clicked on a reaction in discord but is not coming out right  it seems to display the user after getting both choice printed in console log

````
choices = {
        "": "yes",
        "": "No"
    }


    message.channel.fetchMessage(messageid ).then(r => {
        r.reactions.forEach(async (H) => {
            console.log(choices[H.emoji.name]);
            users = await H.fetchUsers();
            await  users.forEach(g => {
                    console.log(g.username);
                });

        });
       ```
but I am getting 
yes 
no 
bob 
Sarah
luke 
john  
when I am trying to get 
yes 
bob 
Sarah
luke 
No
john
````

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is your async forEach is running concurrently, awaiting within the callback function does not stop the loop from moving on to the next iteration.  You may even see slightly different results each time your run it.  Logging the Emoji name goes pretty quick so this finishes in each iteration first and then waits on the fetchUsers, resulting in the yes and no being first.

A possible fix would be to move your line `users = await H.fetchUsers();` up to the top of the loop code, it would then not even start outputting till it had all the information it needs. You should also be aware that Collection.forEach does not return a promise and therefore awaiting your `users.forEach` is unnecessary.

However, this is not an ordering guarantee because the No list might get output before the Yes list.  One way to guarantee ordering will be to remove the loop entirely and handle each emoji in code after an await of the previous one.  Alternatively you could fetch the users in one loop, store them in a persistent collection while waiting with a [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) then output them in a second loop iterating over the stored names fetched.

```js
message.channel.fetchMessage(messageid).then(r => {
   let reactions = r.reactions.array();
   let promises = [];
   reactions.forEach(re => {
        promises.push(re.fetchUsers());
   }

   let users = await Promise.all(promises);

   for(let i = 0; i = reactions.length; i++)
   {
        console.log(choices[reactions[i].emoji.name]);
        users[i].forEach(u => console.log(u));
   }
});
```

Comment: hi can you put an example of what you would think is the best choice

Answer (score 0):

ok after looking at your code I get stuck at reactions[i].emoji.name undefined emoji but if I do the code this way it works

```
        let reactions = r.reactions.array();
        let promises = [];
        reactions.forEach(re => {
            promises.push(re.fetchUsers());
        });

   let users = await Promise.all(promises);
        let i = 0;
        reactions.forEach(re => {
            console.log(choices[re.emoji.name]);
            users[i].forEach(u => console.log(u.username));
            i++;
        })
    });
```